# Why are my React state values not updating synchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create the logic for a card matching game using React. Each card component has a flip value that should update whenever the onClick method is activated. onClick should also update the current turn and save the className to either idA or idB.

However, the cards only begin to update their `setIsFlipped` value once the IDs are set.

```
export const Card = ({
  className,
  flipKey,
  setIDA,
  setIDB,
  idB,
  idA,
  turn,
  setTurn
}) => {
  const [flipID, setFlipID] = useState("");

  const [isFlipped, setIsFlipped] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (flipID === flipKey) setIsFlipped(true);
  }, [flipID]);

  function onClick() {
    setFlipID(flipKey);
    if (turn === 0 || turn === 1) {
      turn ? setIDB(className) : setIDA(className);
      setTurn(turn + 1);
    }
  }

  var classNameString = "card " + className;

  return (
    <>
      {turn}
      {idA}
      {idB}
      {isFlipped ? <p> Flipped </p> : <p>Not Flipped</p>}
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        <div className={classNameString} />
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

The first click updates `turn` and `idA`. The second click updates `turn` and `idB`.

After `turn == 2`the if statement in `function onClick()` stops executing and additional button clicks will cause `setFlipId(flip)` to work. I have tried calling `setIsFlipped(true)` inside of `function onClick()` (instead of matching IDs using `useEffect`) and I got the same results.

Considering that eventually `flip` will be tied to animation transformations I feel quite stuck until I can resolve this problem.

Comment: May you explain better your problem? Really didn't get the `After the if statement..` phrase

Comment: The if condition inside the useEffect references `flipId` but elsewhere it's `flipID` (with a capital D). Not sure if that's a typo in your post or in your code. If it's in your code like that, the state isn't updating because `undefined` will never equal `flipKey`.

Comment: it was an issue with the post but thank you for adding clarity

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that `isFlipped` remains `false` until `turn >= 2`?

Comment: Yes flip remains false until `turn >= 2`.  It seems like the code inside of the if statement blocks the `setFlipID(flipKey)` from executing.

Comment: It works on my machine, sorry to say. Are you sure that you're not on a stale version of the page? Not sure what else I can do.